# Error reading csv files larger than 5 GB in R and duckdb

Tags: r, duckdb

I will load data sets with more than 5Gb per each in duckdb. I need a little help. I start R in the VS Code editor. After some minutes the R stops and gives the message, reload the window. I get an empty example.wal file. The duckbd database is 12 kB big. The output from the dataset is 3 columns with header.

```
# Add libraries
library(duckdb)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

# write to disk as "Example", other defaults to in memory
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "Example")
duckdb::duckdb_read_csv(
    conn = con, name = "Example_csv", files = "data/more/Example-2022.csv",
    header = TRUE, delim = ",", na.strings = "NA"
)

DBI::dbListTables(con)
```

When I use a data set with less data than I get this error message:

```
Error: rapi_execute: Failed to run query
Error: Invalid Input Error: Error in file "example.csv", on line 3: expected 1 values per row, but got more. (  file=example.csv
  delimiter=','
  quote='"'
  escape='"' (default)
  header=1
  sample_size=20480
  ignore_errors=0
  all_varchar=0)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
7: Database is garbage-collected, use dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE) or duckdb::duckdb_shutdown(drv) to avoid this. 
> Error: Invalid Input Error: Error in file "example.csv", on line 3: expected 1 values per row, but got more.
```

Some lines from the data set:

```
DateTime,Beta,Alpha
01/02/2022 22:03:13.151,0.83987,0.84129
01/02/2022 22:05:03.942,0.83959,0.84143
01/02/2022 22:05:09.121,0.83982,0.84124
01/02/2022 22:05:09.286,0.83978,0.8412
```

Comment: Your sample CSV does not trigger that error. Perhaps share the top 5 lines (or so) from the CSV that does? The error clearly suggests that line 3 is not as expected ...

Comment: This are the first 5 lines from the csv file.

Comment: As I said, I used your code on that saved to a file and it did not produce an error.

Comment: I build a new data set and now I get this error:

Error: rapi_startup: Failed to open database: IO Error: Cannot open file "Example": Permission denied

Comment: When I start R this messages will be shown:

source("/home/code-server/Workspace/trader/main.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
Loading required package: DBI

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:

Database is garbage-collected, use dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE) or duckdb::duckdb_shutdown(drv) to avoid this.

Comment: All of that has nothing to do with your core problem: one of your CSVs is corrupted, invalid, or not really comma-delimited.

Comment: Even with the 5 lines I show in this example, I get the same error. Maybe I should reinstall 'R' again, or I didn't install one or the other package?

Comment: Can you include those same 5 lines as raw vectors? E.g. output of `dput(readr::read_lines_raw("example.csv", n_max = 5))`

Comment: If those 5 sample lines saved to a new CSV and then read in with `duckdb::duckdb_read_csv(conn = duck, name = "Example_csv", files = "newfile.csv", header = TRUE, delim = ",", na.strings = "NA")` produces the error, then I suggest first trying a quick read with `read.csv("newfile.csv", nrows=10)` to read in the first 10 data rows to see if it is `arrow` or something else. If `read.csv` does not error, try to add `nrows=10` to your `duckdb_read_csv` expression (it should be passed through). If that fails, then try reinstalling `arrow` (not R).

Comment: This line works for the files:

`data <- read.table("1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fileEncoding = "utf-16")`

Comment: As using `utf-16` seems to work, that must be the encoding of your csv file, it would also explain your `...appears to contain embedded nulls` warings. I think you can pass `fileEncoding = "utf-16"` in your `duckdb_read_csv` call, as according to documentation `...` arguments there are passed through to the `read.csv` call it makes.

Comment: Duckdb can only read UTF-8 files. The problem with my csv files solved. To convert the files is very simple:
`iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 2.csv > 2a.csv`